# Can we use magnetic devices to anchor to asteroids?

Tags: landing, asteroid, future-missions, mining, exploration-mission-1

One of the challenges about missions to asteroids is staying attached to them when you land.

Many asteroids are described as nickel/iron, and we know that both nickel and iron are ferromagnetic.

Is it possible to anchor to a nickel and/or iron asteroid with permanent magnets or electromagnets on landing feet?

If so how close to the asteroid would we need to be to determine if it would be effective? (*I.e. just before landing, or from Earth based testing.*)

Comment: This is a *really interesting question!* For example, consider a "typical" nickel/iron asteroid' if a 100 kg spacecraft had a 10 kg [neodymium permanent magnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neodymium_magnet) segmented (like [these](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Nd-magnet.jpg)) with some degree of  flexibility to accommodate surface roughness, at what diameter would the gravitational attraction be larger than the magnetic attraction? For large asteroids gravity always wins, but for the smaller ones, magnetic attraction could be very helpful, e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzvjp.jpg

Comment: @uhoh Aslong as the poles are facing the correct way gravity and the magnetic force should both be acting in the same direction so it would just aid in staying on the asteroid.

Comment: I think the real issue is finding an asteroid with enough magnetic material on the surface and concentrated in a area so it has a strong enough field to hold. If it's all within the asteroid or spread thin across the surface it wouldn't work.

Comment: @SCLASethKurkowski for large asteroids the force would be unnecessary, you don't carry stuff that has no use, if someone tried to sell you magnetic plating and boots for your lawn on Earth you would politely decline. A definitive answer will identify the size of asteroid for which magnetic locking will provide a useful supplement to gravity.

Comment: @uhoh oh yeah, that. Haha I don’t know what I was thinking with that comment. My second comment was the more thoughtful one.

Answer (score 3):

I see at leat two different aspects here:

## First: Detecting magnetism

Detecting, if the Asteroid is magnetic by itself. The simplest method seems to be holding a magnet close to the asteroid. How close? Very close! At most probably a few meters if you have a really strong magnet (like used in particle accellerators or MRI machines). Using such a magnet on a spacecraft does not seem very practical. If you take a really strong neodynum magnet, we're talking a few centimeters at best. So for all intents and purposes as good as "touching".
**But** there are other ways to detect if an asteroid is magnetic. Measuring the magnetic field around it. The magnetic field that's in our solar system is distorted by the ferromagnetic materials in the asteroid. This field can be measured and a map of the distribution of those materials created from a probe orbiting the asteroid in a safe distance.

## Second: Holding on to an asteroid with magnets

There are different kinds of asteroids. Those, that are (relatively) solid and those, that are basically just a pile of dust and rubble (like Asteroid [Bennu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/101955_Bennu) which was visited by [OSIRIS-REx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSIRIS-REx) that surprised the scientists with it's super loose and soft surface).

Solid asteroids are assumed to have been so hot that the minerals and metals have been liquid in the past. Thus in those asteroids the heavy iron and nickel have sunken down into the core leaving the surface mostly silicates and carbon stuff which is not magnetic. So not much chance of holding on to those bodies with magnets.
On one of the most famous metallic asteroid [16 Psyche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16_Psyche) spectra taken suggest, that the surface consists of silicates (We'll know more when [Psyche (the Spacecraft)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psyche_(spacecraft)) will eventually arrive there)

The other type of asteroids where the iron and nickel are probably still at the surface are ones, that have not been liquid in the past. That means, that the materials (rocks, sand and dust) that they consist of have not separated in different layers acording to their density. But they have also not really had a chance to bond togetther strongly which means, if you put a magnet to those asteroids, the magnet will most probably attract a bunch of sand and dust but not really help anchor a spacecraft to the asteroid.

That said, we're far from knowing what kind of asteroids are out there that will surprise us with the composition they have. So maybe, in a few years we'll have to say that this answer did not age well. But as far as we know right now, magnets do not seem a great way for attaching something to an asteroid.

Answer (score 0):

Small magnets attract a piece of iron over a distance of some millimeters. Medium size magnets over a centimeter or two.

A huge and powerful magnet is needed for distances of some meters.

> For illustration purposes only (these dimensions are not associated
> with specific suppliers of MRI systems), for an unshielded 1 tesla (T)
> (1 T = 10,000 G) MRI system, the 5 G line might be approximately 15
> feet from the magnet bore; the 100 G line, stronger magnetic field,
> might be approximately 8 feet from the magnet bore; and the 10,000 G,
> the strongest field for a 1 T magnet, will be at the entrance to the
> bore.
>
> The magnetic force exerted on an object increases exponentially as it
> nears the magnet. Imagine standing 15 feet (4.6 m) away from the
> magnet with a large pipe wrench in your hand. You might feel a slight
> pull. Take a couple of steps closer and that pull is much stronger.
> When you get to within 3 feet (1 meter) of the magnet, the wrench
> likely is pulled from your grasp. The more mass an object has, the
> more dangerous it can be -- the force with which it is attracted to
> the magnet is much stronger. Mop buckets, vacuum cleaners, IV poles,
> oxygen tanks, patient stretchers, heart monitors and countless other
> objects have all been pulled into the magnetic fields of MRI machines.
> Smaller objects can usually be pulled free of the magnet by hand.
> Large ones may have to be pulled away with a winch, or the magnetic
> field may even have to be shut down.

So a strong MRI magnet of 1 Tesla may be used for a maximum distance of about 5m. The magnetic force is proportional to the square of the distance. So for a distance of 0.5 m a 10 mT (millitesla) magnet will show a slight pull. For 5 centimeters a 100 µT (microtesla) magnet will do.